# php 5.3.x ldap_bind() Failed To ldaps:// With A Self-Signed Cert

Tags: php, openldap

I'm in the process of setting up a new LAMP server on a RHEL 5.6 (x86_64), using Apache/2.2.22 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.22 OpenSSL/0.9.8w and PHP/5.3.13. (I also tried with PHP 5.3.11.)

The issue is that I can't bind to an SSL LDAP server that is using a self-signed cert.

```
TLS certificate verification: Error, self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

Everywhere that I had read mentions modifying ldap.conf to "TLS_REQCERT never" but this isn't working. (This also wouldn't be a permanent solution as the changes are overwritten by some corporate subsystems.)

I also tried putting this in the PHP code:

```
putenv('LDAPTLS_REQCERT=never');
```

Which also did not work.

Three things to note:

1) This same code worked fine in a similar server setup, but was using PHP 5.2.x and had no changes to the ldap.conf file.

2) When running the same PHP script via CLI instead of through Apache, it works fine

3) If I remove the ldaps:// connection and just use ldap://, it works without issue.

I can't figure out why changes to the ldap.conf are not working correctly and why the CLI would work, even when ldap.conf isn't modified.

Edit:

I no longer think the cert check is the issue but I am still struggling to get ldaps:// working when run from Apache.

Here is the debug when run from the CLI:

```
TLS certificate verification: Error, self signed certificate in certificate chain
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write finished A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 flush data
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read finished A
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
```

And here is the same when run under Apache:

```
TLS certificate verification: Error, self signed certificate in certificate chain
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server certificate A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 read server done A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:SSLv3 write client key exchange A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 write finished A
TLS trace: SSL_connect:error in SSLv3 write finished A
TLS: can't connect.
```

So, it seems the cert errors in either scenario, which is fine, but when run as a web module, I get TLS: can't connect versus a successful connection.

Both phpinfo() and php -i are identical with regards to OpenSSL and LDAP options.

Comment: Obligatory: SSL without validating the cert is about 0% more secure than no SSL.

Comment: This is on an internal, corporate network, so I'm not concerned about the validity of the cert. LDAP over SSL means the traffic itself is encrypted, which is my end goal, since this is for authentication and passwords are being supplied.

Comment: Someone who could snoop the passwords from the non-SSL connection could MITM and then snoop the passwords from the SSL connection, and you'd never know, unless you validate that the cert actually belongs to a legitimate server.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to solve the issue. Unfortunately, it was more of a odd case of user error rather than some unknown bug.

I remembered back when I was compiling all of the pieces of the LAMP stack, that I originally compiled OpenSSL with the -fPIC parameter. httpd was linked against that.

While I was compiling php 5.3.11, it complained that the SSL libs should have been compiled with "shared" instead, so I recompiled OpenSSL (same install dir) and linked PHP against that.

Apparently, httpd was having issues using the OpenSSL libraries because of this, so I recompiled httpd against the new OpenSSL libraries and re-installed over itself.

SSL over LDAP is working now.